# How do I control the amount of JavaScript Ajax Control Toolkit spits out?

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

With the Ajax Control Toolkit, one can easily drag and drop all types of great extender onto controls, but they register a boatload of JavaScript to do it.

1. How do I control this?
2. If the `ScriptManager` is in the `MasterPage`, is there anyway to control the loading of a script on one page that isn't in another?

For example: calendar extender is on one page, but the script for it gets loaded on every page that is a child of the master page.

Answer (score 1):

I'd love to have an answer to this, as well.
The toolkit's blind insertion of javascript,
without regard to best practices, has led our
devs to make ridiculously large pages.

The whole POINT to the toolkit is to make design
easy, but now we have to refactor our entire UI,
because of the 'ease' it provided. We're sending 
HUGE pages out, which we cannot cache.

Answer (score 1):

Consider moving away from the Ajax control toolkit. The huge JavaScript load is the reason why we are moving away from it. You should consider a library such as jquery.